# Place loader in the middle of the Google Docs plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a Google Docs plugin using Apps Script.
I want to have a loader when a user performs some action where I pull data from the server.

Here is how my CSS looks:

```
/* Loader styles */
.loader {
  display: none;
  position: fixed; /* Change back to fixed positioning */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent background */
  z-index: 9999; /* Ensure the loader is on top of everything */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.loader .spinner {
  border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); /* Border color */
  border-top: 4px solid #3498db; /* Top border color */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite; /* Rotation animation */
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="loader" id="loader" style="display: none;">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
  </div>
```

All the content is inside the sidebar's div, with the following styles:

```
.sidebar {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
      width: 300px;
    }
```

However, my loader is placed in the left top corner, not in the middle of the page.
How can I fix it?